# OpenCart v1.5.5.1 - Language selector

Tags: jquery, module, opencart, lang

I've passed the last hour trying to find information on how to change the language of my opencart page, without changing it forever.

Basically, i know everything about the language packs, and creating your language, but i need to know how a custommer on the page can directly chose his language.

I've been looking around to find a way to change the language directly on the page, but it seems nothing is set in stone, just as if it was already there. Although, i did look a the demo pretty solid and haven't seen flags or language places.

(Here, i am not talking about going in the backend and to change the language, but more like the client way to chose his language he wants !)

If somone knows the "url" or the code i need to input in order to change the language, i would be very happy !

Thanks !

Comment: u can try premium extension language translator ,otherwise see this article http://www.tmdhosting.com/tutorials/opencart/opencart-add-language.html

Comment: see this extension , it will do exactly  what you need http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=2407

Comment: @krishna - That just translates, it doesn't switch the language which is what Stacknerd is after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do, though it's not as simple as a URL by default. You need to`POST` the relevant language code to the `module/language` controller to change it. The files you need to look at are

```
catalog/controller/module/language.php
```

and

```
catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/language.tpl
```

Comment: Is it normal that i do not find any language module within my module page ?

Comment: Oops my bad, I thought it was in there - No it's not in 1.5.5.1 its called directly in `catalog/controller/common/header.php` instead

Answer (score 0):

If your language is enabled in the admin section, you should see the language selector in the header at run time.  I do.